# 3D barcharts with cylinders

Tags: python, 3d, bar-chart, enthought, mayavi

I'm having trouble making barcharts using MayaVi with data represented by cylinders instead of rectangular prisms. Is this possible? The following is close, but the cylinder orientations are off, and I have trouble scaling only the height of the cylinder:

```
from enthought.mayavi.mlab import *

s = numpy.abs(numpy.random.random((3, 3)))
barchart(s, mode='cylinder')
```

Comment: It ought to be possible, but probably not with mlab.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for a better 3d plotting package?

Comment: Unfortunately most of my knowledge has been put into mayavi, and I don't know the capabilities of other packages.

That said, you could do it in mayavi, just not with mlab -- instead with some tvtk programming that is considerably more challenging.